# Check what is returning value in condition

Tags: php

Why doesn't this work?

```
function test(){

if($id == 2) {$z = "hello";}
if($id == 3) {$z = "bye";}

return $z;

}

if(test() != "hello"){
echo "bye";
}
else
{
echo "hi";
}
```

How can I check what function returns properly?

Comment: $id has no value inside test() - variable scope? Assignment rather than comparison operator?

Comment: it' just an example, $id is global variable outside of function.

Comment: If you post a question as basic as "why doesn't this work?" - then it helps if you eliminate bad example code that could provide a valid explanation of why something doesn't work; but if $id is a global variable, the function needs to know that, either by your passing it as an argument (the better method) or by use of `global $id;` in the function code

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `==` instead of `=`.

`==` are for comparisons. `=` is for assignment.

Also, as [Mark Baker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/324584/mark-baker) pointed out, `$i` isn't defined within `test()`.

Comment: it was typo. i use == of course for condition..

Answer (score 1):

As you are using a single = sign in your condition, it will always be true.

Currently you SET id to 2 and z to hello then on the next line you SET id to 3 and z to bye.

Change it to == which is a comparison

```
function test(){

  if($id == 2) {$z = "hello";}
  if($id == 3) {$z = "bye";}

  return $z;

}
```